# Not able to POST Variable to Another Page (PHP, Javascript, AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a while loop (inside the "searchvessel.php") that display the content of a query and have a button "upgrade" for each record of that query.

```
`while($fetch = $read->fetch_array()) {
?>
<tr>
<td id="1" style="display:none;"><?php echo $fetch['VesselID']?></td>
<td id="2"><?php echo $fetch['VesselName']?></td>       
<td><input type="submit" class="button" name=<?php echo $fetch['VesselID']; ?> value="Upgrade"/></td>
</tr>`
```

This "Upgrade" button when click will call to a Javascript code that use the value inside the tag name to pass to another page using AJAX.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        $('.button').click(function(){  
            alert($(this).attr('name'));
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: $(this).attr('name')
                },
                url: "vesselrecord.php",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $(".ajaxTest").text("Trying to upgrade...");
                },
                complete: function(){
                    window.location.href = "vesselrecord.php";
                 },
                success: function(data) {
                    $(".ajaxTest").text(data.a);
                    if (data.b == "true") {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
            });             
        });
</script>
```

1. I were able to prompt/alert the value of vessel identification using the "alert($(this).attr('name'));" then
2. Move/Transfer to the "vesselrecord.php
3. But inside the "vesselrecord.php" there is no value in the $_POST['name'].  Looks like there is an issue on my ajax code.  Can you guide me on this? TIA.

Below is my code inside the "vesselrecord.php"

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $vessel_id = strip_tags($_POST['name']);            
}
```

Comment: did you echo the value in vesselrecord.php

Comment: yes and there are no value on the $_POST['name']

Comment: did you see any error in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the location of the window, you make a $get request not $post, that is why you are not getting any value `$_POST['name']`.

You can change the location from-

```
window.location.href = "vesselrecord.php"
```

to-

```
window.location.href = "vesselrecord.php?myquerystringdata=" + $(this).attr("name");
```

and then on you php file you can write code to get value from query string.

Comment: yes, i tried this before.  I was able to capture or get the value of $(this).attr("name") inside the vesselrecord.php using this code and save them on a variable ($vesselID).  But when I tried to save the record inside the vesselrecord.php the value of #vesselID is 0.

Comment: I really want to code this where the vessel id is not pass with the link or reference.  The reason why I prefer to use AJAX, JSON and then the POST command.

Comment: On complete of you Ajax request you have window.location.href = "vesselrecord.php", which means you want to load a new page vesselrecord.php. Now, when you request a new page from server, it is going to be a get request and best way to pass parameters with get request is query string. So the question is what you actually want?

Comment: I want to pass the selected vessel id to the "vesselrecord.php".  Can you give insight on this beforehand, complete and success function?  For this concern, which ajax function should I use.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, Can you please tell me the scenario, that will help me a lot. By scenario, I mean, what is happening on your page and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a while loop that display the vessel list, for every record on that list there is this "Select" button (see code above).  What I want to achieve is when I click the "Select" button it will call (vesselrecord.php and then pass the vessel id to vesselrecord.php.

Comment: can you send the method definition which you want to call? I think thats the last thing missing.

Answer (score 0):

'name' is nested within 'data'. Maybe you need to access data.name? I'm more used to JS than PHP so I'm not sure how to express this. Hope this helps.

```
  data:{
    name:'Al'
  }
```